# how to return Localized text from MVC Controller

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, localization

I am trying to return a string response in Json fromat form an action method, and showing it in a toast message, even thought Culture of the application is set Spanish but it returns text in english. below is my code

```
public ActionResult Search(string keyword)
{
    //Search query and return records.
    //if no record found return Json response with info localized text

    return Json(new {response = LocalizedText.No_Record_Found_Message}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

> If anyone know how to achieve it please post your answer, thanks

Comment: You may check (and post) HOW you set the "application culture". Server has to try to honor client side request.

Comment: can you please explain a little bit more, are there more than one way how we set up the culture?

Comment: Is your web site multi-language?  If not, then just return Spanish strings.  If you want multi-lingual then here: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-create-multiple-languages-in-asp-net-mvc-4-5-framework/ is a reasonable starting point

Comment: Yep there are and some of them aren't the right ones in some contexts